# How to have emails matching a specific Gmail filter sent as SMS to a mobile device?

Tags: gmail, sms

In some cases I receive an email that I would like to know about immediately.  Regardless of whether or not my 'phone has email abilities, SMS messages coming to my mobile are much more in your face. Therefore I am looking for a way to have emails matching some filter in Gmail automatically sent to mobile device via SMS.  Does not need to be the entire message, subject line would suffice.

I am fairly certain this is not possible through Gmail, perhaps I could setup a mailserver on one of my Linux boxes to periodically check for said email and push to SMS via @provider.com.

If relevant at all, I am running an iPhone 3G on T-Mobile but also have a BlackBerry at my disposal.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Create a filter to match your conditions and have the forward the mail to <number>@<provider> or use an Email to SMS gateway. Voting to move this to [Web apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most carriers have free email to sms gateway (standard sms charges apply) meaning you can send an email, which the carrier will convert to sms and send to the phone number.

With this as the case, you can just create an email rule within gmail to forward an email based on your filter rule, and the forward to email would be based on the number/carrier.

Not sure how out of date [This website](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/email-to-sms/) is, so you might have to find a new format to do it, but it is still very possible and easy. I set my gmail to forward an email to me as an sms on ATT.

From the website above the format of the email would be:

T-Mobile:    [10-digit phone number]@tmomail.net
Example: 1234567890@tmomail.net

A quick google search for "forward email to sms" will yield plenty of results.

Comment: Spot on mate, appreciate the answer.  So trivial I should have realized I could just setup a forward, silly but thanks again.

Comment: one more note, I filter by a specific to address: <my address>+phone@gmail.com  You can add +<anything> to your address.  Just a fun tip.

Comment: This no longer works. Gmail now sends email with a confirmation code to any new forwarding addresses to make sure you really own the account. The confirmation code email gets truncated, because it is too long to fit into a text message. The most important information (the actual confirmation code) is too far down in the email, and gets cut off.

Comment: But there is an alternative way to accomplish the same thing for Android.  You can set up a Gmail filter to assign a label (you can call it AndroidNotify or whatever) to incoming email that matches a certain pattern.  Then, on the Android Gmail App on your phone, set up notifications for that label.  More detail here:
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62975/how-can-i-setup-gmail-to-send-me-an-sms-when-i-receive-an-email-that-matches-a-c

Comment: What no longer works? Are you commenting on someone else's answer?

Comment: Man, this is almost 5 years old and with the prevalence of push, I doubt this is necessary anymore. @RobertBrighton your suggestion of using Android Gmail app completely eliminates the SMS requirement, though, so you're answering a different question. If someone really did need SMS, I'd suggest IFTTT.

Comment: @xdumaine, Is this a US thing? Because I'm certain that free gateways don't exist.

Comment: IFTT from linked question works for Americas, and also for me (East Europe):
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62975/how-can-i-setup-gmail-to-send-me-an-sms-when-i-receive-an-email-that-matches-a-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

But you'll have to create your own applet, it's easy (see comments there)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll post a separate answer here. I've found at least two working solutions (for Ukraine, East Europe) as of July 2018.

First has capacity of 100 free SMS/month in USA and 10 sms/month in other countries:

1. Go to https://ifttt.com/ and register there.
2. Click "My Applets" => Create new applet.
3. Click on "This" and choose "Gmail" (use search to find Gmail).
4. Click on "That" and choose "SMS".
5. Complete setup by entering your phone number, and other required information.

Second solution is from https://www.cloudhq.net/ : register there, go to Dashboard, click on "Gmail SMS alerts", then go to your Gmail and click on SMS icon on the top-right of page. Enter you phone number and filters for e-mails. I don't know how many SMSs can send this app.